# Check if a file is already copied

Tags: java, file-io, io, file-handling

I am writing a small program to copy files. The program checks whether the file to be copied is already copied to the destination location.

To verify if the same file exists, I am comparing following two things:

1. Size of the files (of source & destination files).
2. Last modified timestamp.

But, I have following problems doing this in Java:

1. File.length does not return the same number (a difference of 1 is there) when the files are copied using Java IO (Input/Output stream).
2. When the file is copied using Java IO, the last modified timestamp of the copied file is the current date/time instead of the original one.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why you don't check if the file in the new destination exists ?

Comment: @Guillaume - checking wether the file exists is not sufficient for determining if the file has changed.

Comment: Consider looking at the source for Ant's Copy task as it does the same thing.  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Comment: @Guillaume This is the requirement, as the source folder is incremently adding files. When my program copies, it checks if the same file (name, size & date) are same, otherwise copies it again.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand, I think you can check the md5sum instead of the size !

Comment: Thanks all for your comments & answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If size is different you have a bug in your code. I can suppose that
   you are dealing with text files and do not process correctly new
   line character. If you want to *copy* files you should work with
   bytes. Obviously this is assumption only: you have not posted any
   piece of your code.
2. This is correct. The new file is only a copy of the original one.
   Its last modification date is the date when *this* file was last
   modified, i.e. when you finished to write it. To change is use
   `File.setLastModifed()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That helped. There was a bug in my program :)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would calculate the MD5 sum of the original file and compare it with the MD5 sum of the target file, if they're equals, then you're good to go.

Other easy technique is copy the file and append it a suffix while copying and after the process that copies it finishes, remove the suffix on the file name so in that case you'd only check for file existence.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to copy the attributes as well, I know the Files class has a copy attribute option: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

for copying one file into another you can use any class, but i am not understanding why id it necessary to use the timestamp for checking if the file is already copied.

you can check the contents of destination file and the source file, if they match then the file is copied if not then the file isn't copied

another approach will be use the lastModified method of the file class... first one seems a better option